# How to receive scheduled notification (Local Notification) from iphone to apple watch

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit, unusernotificationcenter, unusernotification

I would like to know that whether we can receive scheduled local notification from iphone device and we can receive that notification on Apple watch. I also want to update the status in my local database from that notification.

Note:
The app is local, it's not remote and have local database in which we have to update the status of that notification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check following table from Apple and
[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at the moment. Unfortunately, the only way to receive notifications on Apple Watch at the moment is to have the iPhone locked.